# Como eu faço para retornar o maior e menor valor dentro um laço for usando o Twig?

Tags: twig

Eu faço uma listagem de alguns produtos e precisaria retornar o maior e o menor valor dos produtos sem usar o max e min na consulta em SQL. Tentei usar por exemplo a função [max()](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/max.html) do Twig, mas retorna alguns erros. Segue abaixo o que eu fiz e o erro que está acontecendo:

**Código:**

```
{% for product in produtos %}
        {% set maxValue = max(product.valor)%}
        Valor--->>{{maxValue}}
{% endfor %}
```

**Erro:**

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("max() [<a href='function.max'>function.max</a>]: When only one parameter is given, it must be an array")
```

Comment: O problema do max é até fácil resolver com `{% set maxValue = max(product.valor, maxValue)%}` ou algo parecido, porém pode ser que isso não seja suficiente para a sua lógica.

Comment: @MarcosRegis não funcionou. Eu preciso retornar esse valor para usar em um filtro de preço personalizado onde o valor máximo seria o maior valor dos produtos listados. Eu não estou usando o max() na consulta em SQL pois ao realizar a busca eu passo outros parâmetros como as caracteristicas do produto e  para eu fazer um select max(produto.valor) from produto eu teria que fazer duas buscas diferentes mas passando as condições da busca principal da listagem dos produtos.

Comment: mas ele não ficou armazenado em maxValue??

Comment: @MarcosRegis, fiz exatamente como você mostrou no exemplo mas não funcionou

Comment: isso deveria funcionar `{% set maxValue = 0 %} 
{% for product in produtos %}
        {% set maxValue = max(product.valor, maxValue) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ maxValue }}`

Comment: Agora funcionou. Acho que eu acabei digitando alguma coisa errada. Obrigado Cara!

Comment: Coloquei como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente assim

```
{% set maxValue = 0 %} 
{% for product in produtos %} 
{% set maxValue = max(product.valor, maxValue) %} 
{% endfor %} 
{{ maxValue }}
```